# Expected value equal zero in Chi-square ($\chi^2$) test

Tags: data-mining, chi-squared-test

I'm working on my final project, and it's a QUEST algorithm, and it uses the chi-square test. I have a problem where the expected value = 0.

1. What should I do?
2. What does it imply to the chi-square test or to the QUEST algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand. The expected value of chi-square is the df. But I don't see what you are doing.

Comment: I guess what is meant is that at least one of the expected frequencies is zero. A short comment, expanding @Peter Flom's comment, is that you should show us how this arises: it shouldn't happen, as the implication is that the corresponding category, or combination of categories, is impossible. Otherwise you could aggregate categories to avoid this. Ancient authorities recommended minimum frequencies of 5, but this is very conservative; minimum frequencies of 1 may well be tolerable.